# Android private key issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

By default i have key in adbkey file so should i require to generate my own private key.
As I tested the app on various android phone its working fine and also i dont have to publish in Google PLAY.
I have tested the app on `Android 2.2` to `4.1` its working there.

Suggest what should i do???

or should i go for below 
[link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key)

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#DebugMode

Answer (score 0):

As per official documentation "Your reputation as a developer entity depends on your securing your private key properly, at all times, until the key is expired.".
You can use automatically generated key if you not planning to put your app on google play.